# Obtener el ultimo elemento de un array o arreglo de objectos

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola espero me puedan ayudar con este problema de antemano muchas gracias.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
 var valores_persona;
 
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "frmPersonas.aspx/ObtenerPersonas",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{id_bonos:"' + id_persona + '"}',
                async: false,

                success: function(data) {

                    if (data != '') {
                       
                        valores_persona = data.d;
                   }

                },

                  error: function(error) {
                    alert(error.responseText);
                    console.log(error.responseText);
                    jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(Error.responseText);
                    alert(error.respose.Text);
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```

Donde **valores_persona** me regresa el siguiente resultado:

```
valores_persona = [
                    {"nombre":"Luis", "Edad":"48", "Puesto":"Gerente"},
                    {"nombre":"Alex", "Edad":"27", "Puesto":"Analista"},
                    {"nombre":"Jana", "Edad":"32", "Puesto":"RH"},
                    {"nombre":"Alma", "Edad":"37", "Puesto":"Ventas"},
                    {"nombre":"Jose", "Edad":"35", "Puesto":"Marketing"},
                   ]
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo obtener siempre el ultimo elemento de este arreglo de obtejos.

En este caso quiero obtener el elemento 5:

> {"nombre":"Jose", "Edad":"35", "Puesto":"Marketing"},

pero si se agrega otro elemento quiero obtener el ultimo elemento osea el 6.

Gracias espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Aclara si quieres el resultado en javascript como sugiere alanfcm en su respuesta on en c# o asp.net como indicas en tu pregunta en las etiquetas. Tal vez quieras editar la respuesta para explicarlo o quitar las etiquetas.

Comment: Hola @track3r he quitado las etiquetas por lo que solo es en javascript o jquery.

Comment: Gracias! así nos ayudas a mantener esto más limpio y es más eficiente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo con `length` asi:

```js
valores_persona = [
                    {"nombre":"Luis", "Edad":"48", "Puesto":"Gerente"},
                    {"nombre":"Alex", "Edad":"27", "Puesto":"Analista"},
                    {"nombre":"Jana", "Edad":"32", "Puesto":"RH"},
                    {"nombre":"Alma", "Edad":"37", "Puesto":"Ventas"},
                    {"nombre":"Jose", "Edad":"35", "Puesto":"Marketing"},
                   ]
                   
                   console.log(valores_persona[valores_persona.length-1]);
```

Comment: Hola @alanfcm he colocado el resultado que me colocaste y efectivamente obtuve el resultado que espero pero tengo una duda acerca de si no existirá un problema ya que valores_persona no esta declarado como Array() solo esta igualada con data.d por el momento no obtengo ningun error en consola y obtengo el valor esperado.

Comment: Si data.d es un array no hay ningun problema.